# Nativescript with sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to create an app with nativescript

Where I have a website running and I can for example add an restaurant and a different page with a menu. This will then be added to the database. The app would then upon opening call that information.

Is this possible? Or what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Could you provide some more info about your project and what you are trying to achieve. Regarding to that, you could use nativescript-sqlite plugin, which could helps. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite

Comment: @NikolayTsonev i don't think that he's talking about an InApp Db but a remote Database which is in SQLlite. 
If i am right, you need to create a WebService which will call your database and return the result in JSON (or XML) depending of your implementation. Then your mobile application will call this WebService and you could display your restaurant list :-)

Comment: @Kansen Thank you for your response, but if im using angular i don't use XML or JSON right?

Comment: Firebase realtime database is an easy option for similar scenario - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/DATABASE.md